# python - Understanding ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.xxx' (Relative Imports)

Tags: python

For example I have this package:

```
└── package
   │   __init__.py
   │   first.py
   │   second.py
```

and in my first.py

```
#first.py

def foo(): pass
```

in second.py

```
#second.py
from .first import foo
if __name__=='__main__':
    foo()
```

Now if i try to execute the second.py as:

```
$ cd package
$ python3 second.py
```

I got this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.first'; '__main__' is not a package
```

why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

You should add first.py to second.py without dot

```
#second.py
from . import first
if __name__=='__main__':
    first.foo()
```